# looking for the best way to connect to an SSH server with ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssh, webserver

I have a website running on Node built from ReactJS and I want to have an option to send a file to an SSH remote server by entering IP, username and password.

I have been looking at large number of options but kept getting errors. I tried `npm i ssh2` and `node-ssh` but both doesn't seem to be working well with React..

The simplest thing I tried was building a fresh website using `npx create-react-app` and adding `node-ssh` to it. I then tried adding the simple line of code

```
const { NodeSSH } = require('node-ssh');
const ssh = new NodeSSH();
```

But I kept getting these errors and after a lot of digging it seems like this is not the right way of approaching this.
This is why I need your help.. I believe there has to be a way to access SSH server from a node webserver..

Thank you

Comment: You _can_ access a SSH server from node.js, you just can't do it from client side react code.

Comment: You won't be able to connect directly from the browser/client, those are different protocols, which is why a React app from `create-react-app` didn't work. You're going to need to talk from your React app through a Node server. If you're not very familiar with Node, I recommend reading the docs for Express and node-ssh and seeing then seeing if you have any further issues.

Comment: Thank you @ZacAnger! I am not very familiar yet, thanks for the reading recommendations. Would that mean that I need to deploy another server for the SSH client?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to deploy a Node service. You can use the same one to serve your React app (because you'll want to build static files with `npm run build`, not use the development webserver built-in to create-react-app). The Express docs include that (express.static)

Comment: Again, thank you so much! I'll start doing my reading on Express asap.

Comment: @Linir There are also other popular server frameworks. Express is the most popular by far, but if you don't like the feel of it, you could also check out Koa, Micro, or Restify (there are many many others, but these are some of the most common).